# How .class file makes java independent?

Tags: java

I have been reading everywhere that .class file is independent of the platform.
    On one post I read that  OS+PROCESSOR=PLATFORM. The main purpose of JVM is to produce the corresponding machine code from ".class" file.
Machine codes are for only "PROCESSORS" to understand and "not OS"
    So,why is there different flavours of JVM based on OS? What OS has anything to do with machine codes?

Pls make me understand

Comment: I don't think this is a good question for StackOverflow.  It is more of a discussion-based question about design motivations, and peoples' conceptions of what counts as a "platform" and "independence", than one that has a definitive technical answer.

Comment: I dont think it is a discussion.It is technically said that java is independent.My question was what are the things that make java independent.I am crystal clear when it comes to processor,cos assembly instructions differ for every processor but how is OS involved, why there are different JVM's based on OS? on what technical basis??

Comment: @user2301829 - a) the JVM not necessarily produces machine code. b) The JVM must interface with the OS. Think about this. How would you read a file in Java if the JVM didn't do that?

Answer (score 3):

The JVM (think the Java compiler) *IS* platform dependent as it speaks to the underlying OS to perform its duties. However, the resultant byte code (your .class files) can be run by any JVM *providing* it does not use any OS specific libraries.

Significantly more detail can be found by reading up on Java [through the Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/intro/definition.html)